# In MATLAB, how do we classify or regress using a partitioned model?

Tags: matlab, cross-validation

It seems that cross validated models cannot be used with the *predict* function. How would one go about using the model with a test set? For example:

```
ens = fitcecoc(X, T, 'KFold', 10)
```

Directly using the *predict* function throws an error and MATLAB documentation explains why it does so very [well](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitrtree.html#bt6cr84-3). *ens* is a partitioned model with 10 different classifiers. Should we run *predict* using each classifier and then use the class with the maximum agreement?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of other similar question haven't received answers so I figured I'll answer my own question with the solution I found. MATLAB K-Fold cross validation produces K different classifiers or regressors. They have been generated by holding out portions of data (holdout operation is random, hence if you have an unbalanced dataset - be careful). In order to *predict* the output class, you could iterate over all the trained K models and use *mode* to get the accurate class.

```
cv_Ensemble = crossval(Ensemble_Model, 'KFold', 10);

classIdx = zeros(N, length(cv_Ensemble .Trained));

for p = 1:length(cv_Ensemble .Trained)
      [temp, ~] = predict(cv_Ensemble.Trained{p}, Data_f);
      classIdx(:, p) = temp;
end

classIdx = mode(classIdx, 2)
```